# Strip and tranwrd converting trailing spaces to trailing dashes

Tags: sas

I am trying to convert a text file name I have read in into a legal dataset name in SAS version 9.0.

The code I am using is this (where fnames is a dataset containing text file names):

```
data fnames;
set fnames;
filename2 = scan(filename, 1, '.');
filename3 = tranwrd(filename2, "_", "-");
filename4 = strip(filename3);
filename5 = tranwrd(filename4, " ", "-");
/*filename4 = compress(filename3);*/
filename4 = cats('_', filename4);
drop filename2 filename3;
run;
```

I want this to replace any spaces in my file name with a dash, but not the trailing spaces at the end of the file name (field length and format are both $200. but the string lengths themselves are variable. My input looks like this:

```
1080528-19-08-2016-Man Utd-v-Southampton.txt
```

...and my output looks like this:

```
1080528-19-08-2016-Man-Utd-v-Southampton----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

...when it should look like this:

```
1080528-19-08-2016-Man-Utd-v-Southampton
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to drop the .txt extension from the file name?

Comment: yes i do, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All SAS character variables contain spaces through to the end of their length.  That is unavoidable - so you will need to always work with TRIM every time you translate spaces.  You can't work piecemeal quite like you are because of that - the `strip` doesn't really do much (it left-aligns it if it's not already, but that's it) since it doesn't get rid of those spaces.  There is no `varchar` concept in SAS.

So, this:

```
filename5 = tranwrd(filename4, " ", "-");
```

Needs to be:

```
filename5 = tranwrd(trim(filename4), " ", "-");
```

At minimum.

I would note that it's confusing why you are translating `_` to `-` when `_` is legally part of a SAS dataset name and `-` is not generally.

Perhaps:

```
filename_fin = cats('_',translate(scan(filename,1,'.'),'__',' -'));
```

So:

```
data _null_;
  length filename $200;
  filename= '1080528-19-08-2016-Man Utd-v-Southampton.txt';
  filename_fin = cats('_',translate(scan(filename,1,'.'),'__',' -'));
  put +4 filename= / filename_fin=;
run;
```

I would note that this still is probably not a valid `memname` as it's over 32 characters.